# Como obtener tres objetos aleatorios

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer que me imprima tres objetos de manera aleatoria, esto es lo que he logrado intentar hacer, como observan trate de hacer con el método map, pero imprime los tres primeros objetos, la idea es que me imprima tres objetos de manera aleatoria, pero tiene que ser mayor 75 y no tiene que ser repetido

```
const base = [
    {
      name: "uno",
      rat: {
        est: 75
      }
    },
    {
      name: "dos",
      rat: {
        est: 80
      }
    },
    {
      name: "tres",
      rat: {
        est: 95
      }
    },
    {
      name: "cuatro",
      rat: {
        est: 55
      }
    },
    {
      name: "cinco",
      rat: {
        est: 45
      }
    },
    {
      name: "seis",
      rat: {
        est: 85
      }
    },
    {
      name: "siete",
      rat: {
        est: 95
      }
    }
  ];


 const shuffle = (array) => {
  let r = array
   .filter((i) => i.rat?.est >= 75)
   .map((i: any) => base[Math.floor(Math.random() * base.length)])
   .slice(0, 3);
   return r.length === 3 ? r : array.slice(0, 3);
 };



  console.log(...shuffle(base));
```

Answer (score 2):

Si se trata de extraer tres objetos de forma aleatoria bastaría con algo como esto:

```
const someItems = base.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, 3);
```

Lo que hace el código es ordenar el array de forma aleatoria y luego extrear los primeros `3` elementos con `slice` ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38571132/5587982)).

Si quieres otras cosas aparte de eso, debes especificarlo en la pregunta. Lo digo porque en tu código se hace una serie de verificaciones que no vienen al caso para una selección aleatoria.

```js
const base = [
    {
      name: "uno",
      rat: {
        est: 75
      }
    },
    {
      name: "dos",
      rat: {
        est: 80
      }
    },
    {
      name: "tres",
      rat: {
        est: 95
      }
    },
    {
      name: "cuatro",
      rat: {
        est: 55
      }
    },
    {
      name: "cinco",
      rat: {
        est: 45
      }
    },
    {
      name: "seis",
      rat: {
        est: 85
      }
    },
    {
      name: "siete",
      rat: {
        est: 95
      }
    }
  ];

const someItems = base.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, 3);
console.log(someItems);
```